# Setting Vanity Link in DXA .Net

Tags: dxa, dxa2.2, sites-9.1, .net

I am going to set vanity links in DXA application. The vanity links are updated dynamically so we are managing that in Tridion Component. We use that Component data to create `Alias.config` file and put that in root DXA application folder and use *IIS Rewrite Module* to handle the vanity links. But this works only for the parent site like ABC.com. When we are launching another geo site like abc.com/aa the same set of vanity link does not work there. For that we have to add again new set of vanity link like below:

For **abc.com** :  `<add key="/vanity1" value="/target1/" />`

For **abc.com/aa** : `<add key="/aa/vanity1" value="/aa/target1/" />`

As we have multiple geo sites, if we go with this solution we have to add a lot of such duplicate entries. Also this will increase the size of alias.config file and may cause the application to break.

Can any one guide me with the solution for such problem.

**We are using a single Web application to handle all geo requests.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think the application will break with size increase of the config file? I'd seen huuuuge files and the module continued working with no issues at all.

As for the urls and rules, personally I'd use Regex in the rules for both matching and rewriting.

Comment: The default size of alias.config in Microsoft server is set to 256KB. If the file size goes beyond that the site will go down.

Comment: We have set regx. But as per the requirement we have a lot of vanity which are not falling in any kind of rule. The vanity links for marketing

Comment: It seems the answer here isn't quite specific to Tridion Sites, but rather in IIS or .NET.. 

In IIS, there appears to be an option to increase the maximum size for at least the web.config file, though it's a registry change. You're already using the option to move configuration into a separate file. See this [Microsoft Tech Community post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/web-config-file-maximum-size-and-count/ba-p/1607958) for details.

Otherwise, you might consider handling the rewrite with .NET rather than IIS.

Comment: @Manas.p As mentioned by Alvin, question is not specific to DXA but more over to web.config size limit with IIS approach of handling rewrite/redirects. You may opt for doing the redirects at either application level or at Infra level(Proxy/load balancer/CDN)..